# Firestore doesn't load documents

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a Firebase project that, a few hours ago, stopped loading documents from collections, I can't see them from Firebase console.
I don't know what happened, I'm using Safari on Mac and the only hint I have is the "notifications" voice in the top-right corner of the screen.
It said that my security rules are too weak so I changed a little bit. Maybe my database rules aren't good take a look at them please :

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

First time dealing with this issue, any ideas?

Comment: Firebase Rules just to **Protect** your data not **show** them in the Console .. This Rules allow read or write if User is Auhenticated

Comment: I know but I had a notifications in the top right corner that said "Security rules for your project are too weak" and now Firestore doesn't load documents anymore. I don't know if this is the problem or I should check elsewhere

Comment: Please add more details to your question to know what is the problem you are facing :)

Comment: Yes .. Your Rules are **So Weak** Anyone can Hack your DB .. Beacause you choosed Test Mode while Creating your Firestore DB So after 30 Days your DB wil denied any access to Your DB (This means your App won't work) So to solve this problem .. Create Strong Rules (To Create Rules it depend on What is your DB Structure and How users use This Structure

Comment: Ok thanks, are there any guidelines on : How many rules are needed and others? I read docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started but they're not so useful

Comment: As I saied above it depends on What is your DB Structure (As I can not help Beacause do not know what is the purpose of App Or How Data Stored) .. Just do not give access to your entire DB (Give acess for specific Collections or Documents This will be more security)

Comment: Ok I got you on the DB structure, everyone has its own structure so you can't help me this is clear, ok I'll try to limit the access.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231172/discussion-between-kevin-m-mansour-and-federico-darmini).

Comment: If you can add Your DB Structure in Question .. The Community Can help you ...

Comment: Security rules on their own do nothing. Please edit your question to also show the [**minimal**, complete/standalone code that anyone can run to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen solved! Add more rules fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Solved adding 4 new rules! I think the solution is to add rules since each main collection (each root) has some.

```
service cloud.firestore {

  match /bucket/{anyFile=**} {
    allow read,write: if true;
    allow update, delete : if false;
  }
  
  match /ids/tabs/{lettera}/{nome=**} {
    allow read, create,get,list : if true;
    allow update, delete : if false;
  }
  
  match /uids/{twoLetters}/{UserUid}/{anyDoc=**} {
    allow create : if true;
    allow read,get,list : if true;
    allow update, delete : if false;
  }
  
  match /{stato}/{provincia}/{paese}/{lavoro}/users/{anyDoc=**} {
    allow create,read,get,update,list : if true ;
    allow delete : if false ;
  }
  
}
```

I will change them later to keep all safer, but for now this solved.

Comment: Good to hear you got it fixed .  Can you show the working rules?